# ActiveAndroid One-To-Many relationship with Cascade

Tags: android, activeandroid

I'm little bit confused about how to create `Model` with `ActiveAndroid` to have two tables related with `Cascade` condition `onDelete` and coudn't find any good/clear example to learn from.
so i have this table :

```
    @Table(name = "CheckList")
    public class CheckList {

    @Column(name = "Title")
    String Title;
    @Column(name = "After")
    Integer After;
    @Column(name = "Before")
    Integer Before;

    @Column(name = "Enabled")
    Boolean Enabled;

    @Column(name = "Info")
    String Info;
}
```

and i need to have list of it in this table :

```
@Table(name = "Equipment")
public class Equipment {

    @Column(name = "Title")
    String Title;

    @Column(name = "Checklists")
    List<CheckList> Checklists;

}
```

also i may have another table with list of `Equipment` in it and i need to relate them just like above.

what i want is that when i delete a record from `Equipment` and i need to all record in `List<CheckList> Checklists;` that related to this `Equipment` to be deleted as well. i know i can do a query and so on but i need to know is there a better way and right way to do this?

*Please explain with details (how to create relation and query later ) and show an example related to my tables.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set up the tables with a foreign key cascade relationship.

```
@Table(name = "Equipment")
public class Equipment {

    @Column(name = "Title")
    String Title;

    // This method is optional & does not affect the foreign key creation.
    public List<CheckList> items() {
        return getMany(CheckList.class, "Equipment");
    }
}

@Table(name = "CheckList")
public class CheckList {

    @Column(name = "Title")
    String Title;

    @Column(name = "After")
    Integer After;

    @Column(name = "Before")
    Integer Before;

    @Column(name = "Enabled")
    Boolean Enabled;

    @Column(name = "Info")
    String Info;

    //This establishes a relationship between Checklist and Equipment, Any update or delete operations done on Equipment table gets cascaded to the corresponding rows in the Checklist table.
    @Column(name = "Equipment", onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE)
    Equipment equipment;

}
```

---

#### Reference materials:

1. [Reference article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/activeandroid-guide)
2. [Possible values for ForeignKeyAction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31324400/11016588)
3. [Official docs with basics on how to set up relationships & models](https://github.com/pardom-zz/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Creating-your-database-model#relationships)
4. [Closed issue that confirms that CASCADE DELETE works](https://github.com/pardom-zz/ActiveAndroid/issues/33)

Comment: I need more explanation on this . also i don't get you'r example . I did not needed anything to do with `title`. could you please explain with details (how to create relation and query later ) and show an example related to my question ?

Comment: I just used the `title` column as an example. You'd essentially need to keep have a foreign key in the `Checklist` table that is associated with the primary key in `Equipment` table. That way, when a row in `Equipment` is deleted, it gets cascaded to the `Checklist` table.

Comment: your answer dos not help . i can not just copy `onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE` and put it anywhere i want ? i need to know how this works . if that that was the case i would've done it my self . the problem is i don't know how cascade works with List of items and will they be deleted and how can i can i  query that list to related item.

Comment: @lvl4fi4 Check the reference link I added in my answer. I don't have access to my laptop at the moment, I'll try to add the full code when I can.

Comment: Okay, I guess I missed a key point in my answer, my bad. You essentially don't create a List of items, rather you'd create a function that returns the List of items.

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/activeandroid-guide#defining-models

Comment: i appreciate a full example code related to this case. i don't wanna miss anything . whenever you can . thanks in advance

Comment: The item category relationship is basically what you require. The item contains the`category` column,  which acts as the foreign key. In your case, your Checklist table should have a `Equipment` column which can then be used for cascading. The list of Checklists with a specific Equipment can be gotten as a separate function.

Comment: what about the delete ? if i delete  one `Equipment` record, will the related `checklist` be deleted as well? here is what i need: i just need retrieve/delete the related Checklist without doing a lot of loop and query . if that possible if not i have to go old-school.

Comment: Yes, it will. That's the idea behind setting the `category` (or in your case, Equipment) column's onDelete value as Cascade.

Comment: Alright i will do as you said. please update your answer later with example and explanation so i can chose it as right answer for future users .

Comment: @lvl4fi4 I've updated my answer with the example code and also provided the references for further reading.

Comment: perfect ! just quick fix at `return getMany(CheckList.class, "Category");` what `Category` should be?

Comment: My bad, not "category", it was supposed to be "Equipment". It basically informs which column should be used for comparison. I'll update the answer.